# Why isn't TREE(2) = 6?

Tags: number-theory, logic, graph-theory

I was just introduced to the TREE() function, by a [2017 Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3P6DWAwwViU).

In it, Tony Padilla explains a simplified version of the calculation of the TREE function: We are building a forests with as many trees as we can, following certain rules. Each tree in the *n*th forest can't have more than *n* nodes, and each tree in a forest may not "contain" an earlier tree from the same forest (i.e. it can't be "inf-embeddable"). The maximum number of trees in a forest is  `TREE(n)`.

On the way to explaining that TREE(3) is very large, he computes the size of TREE(2) as 3, giving this sequence for the forest (where G is a green node, and R is a red node):

1. G
2. R-R
3. R

However, following the rules as best I can, I can do better:

1. G-G
2. R-R
3. R-G
4. G-R
5. G
6. R

Now, both Padilla and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_tree_theorem#TREE(3)) tell me that TREE(2) = 3, while I have only just learnt about the subject, so **I know I am wrong** - I just don't know why.

Is the explanation in the video over-simplified and I am being misled over the meaning of inf-embeddable? Was there a rule clearly explained in the video that I foolishly misunderstood? Where did I make a misstep?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first tree in the sequence is only allowed to have at most one node, so your "1. G-G" is invalid.

Comment: Ah, so when I said "Each tree in the nth forest can't have more than n nodes", it should have been "The nth tree in each forest can't have more than n nodes." Got it. Thanks.